# Web Mining Via Search Engines

Tags: machine-learning, web-crawler, data-mining

I was apartment-shopping via Google Maps, copying various listings into a spreadsheet so I could more easily compare and attach notes, when I realized how unnecessarily repetitive and inefficient this was. I could easily write a script to automatically query Google and extract the data I need, but to get some of the data (e.g. contact phone number) requires that I follow a link to a listing-specific site and hunt-around for the data, and I've never written a web-crawler that dynamic. What are the common data-mining and/or machine learning techniques and tools for extracting a "best-guess" for a piece of info given arbitrary HTML?

Comment: http://www.google.com/squared and export to Google spreadsheet.

Comment: @aartist, Absolutely brilliant. The field autopopulation results are far from perfect, but the UI is very close to what I was imagining.

Comment: @aartist: why don't you post it as a solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the back-end technique, but helpful as perceived in the comments. Go http://www.google.com/squared and then export the results as Google Spreadsheet or csv data. It names the fields for you and populate the data from web.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Information Extraction.

This video isn't bad. The guy is from Google:

http://videolectures.net/mlas06_nigam_tie/

Check out RapidMiner and its Information Extraction plugin.